# QT diacritic characters from Base64

Tags: c++, qt, base64, decode

I have a problem with getting diacritic characters from strings encoded in Base64 under QT. I'm creating string then I'm encoding it with Base 64 and I'm saving it to file. Next I want to decode characters from opened file. Here is how I do this.

```
void MainWindow::on_treeWidget_2_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index){
    encode("([ęśćźół35:11");
    decode();
}

void MainWindow::encode(QString input){
    QString item_to_change = input.toUtf8().toBase64();
    QString filename="output.txt";
    QFile file( filename );
    if ( file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) )
    {
        QTextStream stream( &file );
        stream << encoded;
    }

}

void MainWindow::decode(){
    QFile input("output.txt");
    if (input.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        data_in = input.readAll();
    }
    QString strRestored(QByteArray::fromBase64(data_in));
    qDebug() << strRestored;
}
```

Doing this I'm getting only ([esczol35:11 instead ([ęśćźół35:11

Please help me to get all chars as entered at the beginning.
Thanks

Comment: If you have a problem with hardcoded string in a source, you need to check what encoding is used for saving the .cpp file in your IDE

Comment: This may just be an artifact of string encoding in your string literal. You should always wrap your string literals with [QStringLiteral](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem isn't in the Base64 encoding/decoding because that's going to return exactly what you put in every time; that's the point of it. My belief is that your call to your "encode" method is converting the string literal, or that the toUtf8 is converting it incorrectly. Print out each of those steps using qDebug to see where the problem is, and then you'll probably need to look at the QTextCodec class to set up the conversions properly.

Comment: You are right. There is a problem with utf8. If I change my encode function to: 
`void MainWindow::encode(const char * input){`
    `QString filename="output.txt";`
    `QFile file( filename );`
    `if ( file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) )`
    `{`
        `QTextStream stream( &file );`
        `stream << input;`
    `}`
`}`

and

`void MainWindow::on_treeWidget_2_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)`
`{`
    `QString Qstr1 = "([ęśćźół35:11";`
    `encode(Qstr1.toUtf8().constData());`
   
`}`

Then I got ([A?A?A?A?A?A?35:11 written to file

Comment: So now I've stuck with conversion from const char to base64. Moreover when I convert from const char to qByteArray then whole codding disappear. I don't know how to get this converted. I just need to pass a text that will be encoded to base64 in a right way that I will be able to decode and get the same result to passed string.

Comment: Try adding this line to your main program (anywhere before you do any UTF-8 conversions):   QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));

Comment: I think the problem is bigger than I thought. I'm working on Windows in QT5 and even doing this:
`QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::Polish, QLocale::Poland));`
`QDate date = QDate::currentDate();`
`QString dateString = QLocale().toString(date);`
`qDebug() << dateString;`
`qDebug() << QLocale().name();`
I'm getting: 
`sroda, 8 lutego 2017`
'pl_PL`
instead "środa , 8 lutego 2017"
What should I change to get right fonts in QT? If it's not right in qDebug then it will not work wit conversions of the strings

Comment: Your question isn't about fonts; it's about character encoding. It's best to ask a new question about the fonts rather than mix it up with this discussion. You haven't said whether you put the setCodecForLocale line in.

Comment: Yes I have set the setCodecForLocale line. I know that my question is not about the fonts because fonts in my running program are fine. I have all special chars in GUI of my program but when do for example `ui->textBrowser->setText(decode(str));` fonts are missing and I'm getting "sacz" instead od "śąćż". To be clear: when doing `ui->textBrowser->setText(decode(str));` or `qDebug() << decode(str);` I'm not getting right fonts but when I do this: `ui->label->setText("śąćż");` I'm getting the right fonts :( Im running my qt on Windows 7 if this changes anything.